# show a different URL or hide URL in video tags src attribute in souce code

Tags: javascript, html, video, src

I dont want to show src attribute of video tag in source code and inspect element.
their is any way to do it using javascript. i want to hide or display different URL in video tags SRC attribute using javascript.

Comment: Can you give us a use case for this? There is nothing (as far as I know) that can truly hide the src from someone with enough patience and knowledge.

Comment: suppose i have one video tag
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
 in this case i dont want to show this src tag in source code.  i want to hide it or display other hardcoded URL over their.

Comment: You can try to leave the `src` attribute empty and then use Javascript to fill it subtly.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **HTML5 video**. What you're requesting is impossible !
There is no way to hide this tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it using HTML5/JS. You can, of course set the src property of video object in DOM using JS but src will be visible in the inspector.